# Is the 1977 film "The Palestinian", narrated by Vanessa Redgrave, available to consumers?

Tags: availability, the-palestinian

At the 1978 Academy Awards ceremony, Vanessa Redgrave received the Best Supporting Actress award for her part in [*Julia*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076245/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_116) (1977). Her acceptance speech became famous because she referred to the people protesting her as "Zionist hoodlums." These people were protesting her because of her involvement in another film, a documentary called [*The Palestinian*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076521/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (1977).

What's become of this latter film? If it was ever available for home consumption, is it still in print?

Comment: Resources to locate or watch movie/TV content are off topic. Please [**follow the tour**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: This should NOT be closed if the OP is requesting a way to view or acquire the film.  Any answers relating to illegal downloads should be edited, but the OP is not asking for illegal download links.  Perhaps it's available on Hulu?  Amazon?  Paramount+?  Or it's out of print or was never completed?  One can not "enjoy" or "understand" a film if they can't view it.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - "questions asking for movies/TV-shows or resources to locate or watch movie/TV content are off topic" Legality is not mentioned. https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Well, I had edited the title to "Is it available to consumers?"  That's a valid question.  I've made an additional edit to remove the request to locate/purchase the film.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Questions asking for resources are banned on almost all SE platforms, and this has been the case for a long time. I'm surprised to see this comes as news to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The film was originally aired as a TV movie, it was never in theaters.  It was never released in a home video format, either.  However, the original Director's son has finally made it available on Youtube.